# Passing variables between EJS files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, variables, get

I've got a problem with passing a clicked variable to another .ejs file when I click on it.

I have a "index.ejs" file which has a list on it in which I show a couple of urls. When I click on one of those urls I want to open a new page "clicked.ejs" and keep the style of "index.ejs" except put that url as title of the new page.

Currently I have this which only alerts in browser on which  url have I clicked.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("ul[id*=myid] li").click(function () {
                 var clickedUrl=($(this).text());
                  alert(clickedUrl);
            });
        });
 </script>
```

---

```
<ul id='myid'>
      <% for(var i=0;i<scrapped.length;i++){%>
          <li><%=scrapped[i].url%></li>

    <%  }%>


    </ul>
```

The urls are read from database and shown in a list on the index.ejs and they are clickable. When you click on one I want to transfer it and write it as content on the new page.

How am I supposed to do this? I managed to like follow the path of the url and open that link but I want to just send that value and display it on another page.

It is probably something with get/post and 
     res.render('clicked',{clicked:url});

Thank you for your time.

Comment: URL parameters.

Comment: @Roberrrt what do you mean by that? To send like www.url.com?parameters